# Get current URL with AppiumLibrary - RobotFramework

Tags: appium, robotframework, python-appium

I use AppiumLibrary with RobotFramework to test web browsing on Android. In several of the test, I need to find out what is the current URL that the user has been directed to after clicking on a link.

The basic sample test case is:

```
Test Appium
   AppiumLibrary.Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub  platformName=Android  platformVersion=6.0.1  deviceName=0815f853b6d22c05  browserName=default
   AppiumLibrary.Go To Url  https://www.amazon.com/
   sleep  5s
   ${current_url}  get current url
   log to console  ${current_url}
```

Unlike SeleniumLibrary, AppiumLibrary does not have a keywork to do this, so I have to create my own keyword for **get current url** in python. I have tried several things looking at the AppiumLibrary source code and also the Appium-Python-Client module that implements the Appium Webdriver for python. But I have not found how to get the current url that chrome is showing to the user.
Any hints on where I should look to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find how to get it working with a new keyword. Basically, I could not find how to access the Selenium driver within the Appium driver that implements a method for that, but I got a much simple and elegant answer from katchdoze in the AppiumLibrary channel of slack robotframework. It is as simple as:

```
Test Appium
   AppiumLibrary.Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub  platformName=Android  platformVersion=6.0.1  deviceName=0815f853b6d22c05  browserName=Chrome
   AppiumLibrary.Go To Url  https://www.amazon.com/
   sleep  5s
   ${current_url}  execute script  return window.top.location.href.toString()
   log to console  ${current_url}
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Appium, but from what I know of Robot framework the following should work:

AppiumExtended.py

```
from appium import webdriver

def get_url():
    url = driver.current_url()
    return url
```

testScript.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library  /path/to/AppiumExtended.py
Library  Other libraries

*** Test cases ***
Test to get url
    ${url}  Get Url   
    Log to console  ${url}
```

[Appium - Get url command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/web/navigation/url/#0_1)

Comment: I tried getting the current webdriver with BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary')._current_application() . This actually returns an the object of type Webdriver that is used by the running Appium instance. But calling current_url() raises "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".